# Referencing an external schema from JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm currently developing a SOAP web service using JAX-WS RI. I've taken a code first approach and so the WSDL is being generated automatically. This is fine, but for one of my operations I'm taking some data that is defined by an XSD that is already defined. The service will simply pass messages of this type on to an underlying component that knows how to process this message. Ideally, when the service receives one of these messages, JAX-B will turn this into an XML element that can be passed to the relevant component, i.e. I don't require any de-serialization into Java types as these types will not be defined (the service itself has no need for them).

I know I can probably use xs:any to achieve this, however I would like the associated types to be referenced from the WSDL and the service to be able to validate the message.

Many Thanks